# how to convert a two column/multiple group groupby() objetc to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I´m finding very difficult to convert this groupby object to dataframe:

```
In: g = df_dea.groupby('client_id')[['balance','transfer_net']]

In: print(g.head(5))

Out:

      balance  transfer_net
0     1000.00       1000.00
1     1000.00       1000.00
2     1000.00       1000.00
3      986.84       1000.00
4      976.72       1000.00
759   5018.71       5018.71
760   5018.71       5018.71
761   5018.71       5018.71
762   5018.71       5018.71
763   4999.25       5018.71
1058  1992.10       1992.10
1059  1990.88       1992.10
1060  1989.67       1992.10
1061  1988.46       1992.10
```

I tried defining this object `as_index=True` or `reset_index()`. It doesn´t work.

This info maybe helps also:

```
In: print(type(g.groups))

Out: <class 'pandas.io.formats.printing.PrettyDict'>

In: print(g.groups)

Out:

{0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...], 1: [759, 760, 761, 762, 763...], 2: [1058, 1059, 1060, 1061]}
```

Comment: `df.groupby("x")` essentially returns dict-like object, having keys as every unique `"x"` as `{x1: df.loc[df["x"].eq(x1)], x2: df.loc[df["x"].eq(x2)], ...}` how do you want it converted into data frame?

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski If the dataframe comes in this printing format: `index` + `balance` and `transfer_net` as columns, is perfect for me. Do I need to run an whole iteration for that?

Comment: But what about `client_id` do you want to aggregate by it anyhow? Or you want `df_dea` with exactly same rows, just without `client_id`?

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski it can be another column, after index and before other columns.

Comment: See my answer - just add `client_id` to index ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is just to move `client_id` into index, so:

```py
df_dea.set_index("client_id", append=True, inplace=True)
```

Instead of `df_dea.groupby(...)`